# Updating parameter in custom layer pytorch during forward pass

Tags: pytorch

I have created the following custom layer in pytorch. The code is very similar to a regular linear layer but there's an added term to each connection (hebb) that sums to the weight. I'm getting the runtime error **RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time (or directly access saved tensors after they have already been freed)** when the code bellow tries to execute the line **self.hebb = torch.matmul(yout.t(), x)**. The idea is that between forward passes this **self.hebb** term is updated such that the consecutive forward passes uses the product of pre/post units activations of the previous forward pass.

```
class LinLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, size_in, size_out):
        super().__init__()
        self.size_in, self.size_out = size_in, size_out
        weights = torch.Tensor(size_out, size_in)
        self.weights = nn.Parameter(weights)
        bias = torch.Tensor(size_out)
        self.bias = nn.Parameter(bias)

        self.hebb = torch.zeros((size_out, size_in), requires_grad=False)

        # initialize weights and biases
        nn.init.kaiming_uniform_(self.weights, a=math.sqrt(5)) # weight init
        fan_in, _ = nn.init._calculate_fan_in_and_fan_out(self.weights)
        bound = 1 / math.sqrt(fan_in)
        nn.init.uniform_(self.bias, -bound, bound)  # bias init

    def forward(self, x):
        hebb = self.hebb

        w_times_x = torch.mm(x, self.weights.t() + hebb.t())

        yout = torch.add(w_times_x, self.bias)  # w times x + b

        self.hebb = torch.matmul(yout.t(), x)

        return yout
```

I have tried **hebb = self.hebb.detach()**, **self.hebb = torch.matmul(yout.t(), x).detach()** and **loss.backward(retain_graph=True)**, which all make the computed loss return NaN. Any idea how can I fix this? Thx in advance.